# Low Level TCP/SSL protocol for db2

Tags: database, tcp, db2, tcpclient, db2-400

I'm working with some legacy piece of software that uses its own client implementation to db2 on top of TCP.

Is the protocol to access db2 via tcp/SSL open and documented somewhere? Or the only way to get some knowledge is to reverse engineer it by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your legacy software implements some part of the [DRDA specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699939399/toc.pdf), which is the set of protocols Db2 uses.

Apache Derby also implements DRDA, so you could use its source code as a starting point.